# как перевести vector<int> в string?

Tags: c++, строки

Решаю задачку по c++. Почти решил,но появилась проблема.

Вызываю функцию `find()` из `string`. Параметром надо передать переменную `string(adapter)`.

У меня есть вектор `vector<int>numN;`. Надо передать в `adapter` `num[1]`(значение есть),то есть`num[1] = 2; adapter = num[1]; cout <<adapter;`и чтоб вывелось `2`. А у меня выводится вопрос в квадратике.

с++,я новенький.

Comment: Сформулируйте свой вопрос так, чтобы его можно было понять. Советую ознакомиться с [mcve](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 4):

```
adapter = to_string(num[1]);
```

Вот и все.

Вам не вектор в строку преобразовывать нужно, а целое число...

То, что вы сделали - это строка из единственного символа с ASCII-кодом 2.